# Getting extra spacee in IE

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Hi I am using jsf and primefaces.

```
   <h:outputText id="abc" value="my text"/>
```

When i disply it in Firefox it looks fine in the browser as **my text** but when run this in IE it will have one extra space at the end like **my text **.

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: What's your PF version?

Comment: what does it show in the view source ? is there an extra space in the source as well ?

Comment: No there is no white space in the view source @Anugoonj